# CALayer not rendering contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, calayer

This one is stumping me. I have a `CALayer` which I create in a `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];

    _imageLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];

    _imageLayer.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    _imageLayer.position = CGPointMake( self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0 );

    _imageLayer.contents = (id)img.CGImage;
    _imageLayer.contentsScale = img.scale;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_imageLayer];
    [_imageLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The `UIViewController` is loaded from a nib and placed into a `UITabBarController` that was created in code.

My problem is that the `CALayer` does not render its `UIImage` contents when the `UIViewController` becomes visible. The only way I can make the `CALayer` to render the `UIImage` is by setting its contents to the `UIImage` after the `UIViewController` is made visible, such as in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

I would really prefer to do all my set up in the `viewDidLoad` method (isn't that what's it’s for?). How do I get the `CALayer` to render its contents?

Comment: Why are you calling `-setNeedsDisplay` on the new layer (which was not modified), and not on your view's layer?

Comment: Just a simple attempt to get it to render.

Comment: Oh wait, I see your point. If I remove the `[_imageLayer setNeedsDisplay];`, it works just fine. What is happening there?

Comment: I mean, setNeedsDisplay needs to be called on the *superview*, not on the subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that `setNeedsDisplay` on the layer, or the superview.

`setNeedsDisplay` tells a layer or view that it needs to redraw its contents. (For a view, it will call `drawRect:` to get new contents; for a CALayer, it will ask its delegate.)  Note that this affects only the view or layer itself, not its children.

Since you are providing the content for the layer directly, you don't want CA to discard that content and ask for a replacement.